# pod install: command not found when called from bash script

Tags: ruby, jenkins, rvm, bash

I'm improving the continuos integration of a project. And we decided to take an extra step and start using cocoapods. All the rvm installation is legacy and indeed I have a lot of troubles installing ruby 2.2.0. The thing is that, when I test my build script using terminal it works fine, but when I try to run them without opening a terminal window (called from applescript, jenkins or another ruby script). The command is not found.

Already tried adding the path to .rvm/scripts to the PATH variable in both .bashrc and .bash_profile

Comment: Have you tried to call the program using its absolute path instead of the relative one?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to reconnect the server after you installed the cocoapods? sometimes it doesn't see the new vars till it disconnected and reconnected.

Also make suer that the vars that you see through the terminal are available for jenkins user. you can check that through the slave "Script Console"

If it still don't work, try to set the path in the "execute shell", just before you run the pod install.

This is how it works for me:

echo "Running pod install"
cd ${WORKSPACE}
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
pod install